# Redirect a part of a URL with .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm trying to make a 301 redirect to a new category name:

http://www.site.com/category1/post1/
to 
    http://www.site.com/category1-new/post1/

There are other pages as well with "category1" in their URL so it has to be exactly "/category1/" and right after the domain name.

I've tried different patterns but they always end in an infinite loop.

EDIT:

Code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site-suchen.de$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site-suchen.de$
RewriteRule ^site\/(.*)$ "http://www.site-suchen.de\/site-new\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

So actual url:

```
http://www.site-suchen.de/site/post1
```

needs to redirect to

```
http://www.site-suchen.de/site-new/post1
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The important things here are probably that you want to have the ^ and $ to mark the beginning and end of your string you're matching.  Although that's just a guess unless you post some code that you've already tried.

```
RewriteRule ^category1/post1/$ category1-new/post1/
```

or it might be (I can't remember exactly whether you specify the / in the pattern and/or substitution strings):

```
RewriteRule ^/category1/post1/$ /category1-new/post1/
```

Comment: Hi sorry if I was not clear but "post1" is dynamic. I also tried this but it still ends in an endless redirect. I've posted my code above which does an infinite loop. I'm guessing it has something to do with "site-new" because without it, it redirects fine.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use RedirectMatch?

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(site1|site2|category1)(/.*|$) /$1-new$2
```

This code would be maintainable in the long run, as you can just add new path inside the parenthesis
( site1 site2 category1 , etc )

I tried this on my localhost, and it should solve your problem

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you, this I think is the best approach but I still get into an infinite loop. Removing the $2 at the end however fixes the problem but only redirects to http://www.site-suchen.de/site1-new/ so the "post1" slug is missing. Can you help me append the last part of the URL back?

Comment: Can you try this? RedirectMatch 301 ^/(site1|site2|category1)(.*) /$1-new$2

Comment: Thanks. It redirects to site-suchen.de/site1-new-new-new-new-new-new-new-new-new-new-new-new-new-new-new-new-new-new-new-new, and then an endless loop..

Comment: Ah, lets put slash outside the parenthesis,
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(site1|site2|category1)/(.*) /$1-new/$2

Comment: Sorry still the same, endless loop. I know that SHOULD work because I've been reading about RedirectMatch too for hours now. Not sure why it still doesn't though. RedirectMatch 301 ^/(site1)/(.*) /$1-new/post1 works however..

Comment: Thats weird. hmmm...
/$1-new/post1 should be the same with /$1-new$2